# my Samsung phone says it doesn't have a rooting system, in laymens terms, how do I fix it

Tags: hardware, system

I installed a memory booster/ security device on my Samsung recently. I have always wondered if I actually need all this hardware and apps in my phone. Now it tells me I can uninstall some apps , when I go to do it my phone says unable to no root system. What do I do?

Comment: First I would be highly suspicious of the program, as "memory booster" sounds like crap - second, it's asking for root privileges, which you are unable to grant unless you have rooted your device - which if you post the exact model, or just search "root *exact model name*", you should be able to get good instructions. Again, I would NOT recommend doing it for this app as it sounds fishy, and will likely make things go badly.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, I agree with @user2813274. You should be very careful about what you try to uninstall as things can go *badly* wrong.

**To answer your question of what to do:**

You need to grant the app root privileges.

To uninstall system apps `root` access is required, which is in basic terms, elevated permissions. The app you have installed is unable to remove some of the apps because they are system apps and it lacks the necessary permissions to do so.

If you need help rooting your device I would check on [XDA Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) for instructions specific to your device.